# How can a retrieve the indicators used against each field of the display file along with this DSPATR attributes

Tags: api, ibm-midrange, display, rpgle, dds-format

I am trying to retrieve the indicators used against each field of the display file along with the DSPATR of the particular fields respectively.

For Example: If I have a field in my display file as given below. I need to identify the field WSCRT along with the DSPATR's 'PC' - 61 , 'RI' - N62 , 'BL' - 63

```
A            WSCRT     R        B  2  9REFFLD(CRT)                
A  61                                  DSPATR(PC)                                
A N62                                  DSPATR(RI)                 
A  63                                  DSPATR(BL)
```

I am trying to use QDFRTVFD API to retrieve the details where I was partially successfull. I was able to retrieve the DSPATR attributes associated with each fields, However I am not able to retrieve the indicators used against each display attributes (DSPATR).

Comment: Adding a point here. I need to retrieve the information only using the display file object. We do not have the Source of DSPF objects

Comment: I came across a command DSPDSPF which can retrieve the display file source from its object. However i am not able to find the source of this command. Do anyone have an idea of this command and the source for this command. It would be great if someone can provide me source for this command.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indicators and fields in a display file with SDA.

- STRSDA
- Take option 3 test display files
- Enter your file your lib
- Press Enter
- Press F4
- Select a Record
- Press Enter

This example is using 3 indicators.

Type indicator settings (1=On, 0=Off), press Enter.
[image]

Press enter to see all the fields.

How the Fkeys and indicators are used is now the only mystery.

Comment: Hi danny, Thank you for your suggesstion. However i want to find all the display attributes (DSPATR) used against the each fields along with the indicators. STRSDA does not seem to be usefull in my case. and more over i wanna get it run time in rpgle program.    I found out that QDFRTVFD API will help me retrieve this information and i am looking for some solution around that. It would be great if someone can help me with this.

Comment: @AKarthik that's the indicators.  If finds them.  Use this to reverse engineer the display file once for each record format.

Comment: i need the display attributes and the indicators associated with each display attributes particularly and i need to retrieve this information runtime in rpgle program

Comment: Trial and error.  The fields show up on the screen (not shown).

Comment: i tried most of the things. Still not able to get the display attributes and its optional indicators. I have been spending almost 4 weeks on this now :(   My bad!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create DS on the subfile record format and use it when you are doing a READC or CHAIN operation on the subfile. This record format will have values in all fields and corresponding indicators as well.